# Feature. Can the mark question as "solved" have a timer?

Tags: feature-request

Let us asume that one person makes a question, and it is inmediatly answered by another user.

Probably it is not the best answer, but it is marked inmediatly as "solved".

Sometimes that prevent other person to write a better answer, or prenvents the asker to have a better understanding of the topic.

Can that option have a timer to be available lets say some 24 hours after the question is asked, and not before?

Comment: There is a timer on accepting answers. It is 15 minutes I believe.

Comment: We want people to get their answers quickly whenever possible! That doesn't stop others from adding more/better answers later

Answer (score 6):

Anyone posing a question is absolutely free to change what answer is the accepted answer at *any* time. You can return 2 years from now and change the answer marked correct. There is an initial delay on marking something correct. I don't remember what it is. @Ryan state's its 15 minutes in the comment above. That sounds about right.

If you are *not* posting answers because you see one is already marked, then you should start. If you have, what you believe is a better answer, by all means share it. Even if the one person who asked the question doesn't mark it correct, you can still help many, many users.

If your concern is just the reputation gained from marked answers, well, I sort of think that's the wrong reason to post any answer. But you can often gain MORE rep with a great answer even if it's never marked as the "selected" answer.

Answer (score 3):

An accepted answer is not permenatly set in stone and if any feel like giving a better answer they are encouraged to do so and the OP will be pinged that their question has another answer.

That said the principal of our system is a question that in fact gets an answer that the OP is after.  You can always encourage the OP to review the new answer and change their mind but id rather have a question with an accepted answer in less than a few minutes than a question with five answers and no accepted answer whatsoever.

Also, i have never seen an answer thst wasnt better not be upvoted with rep which should be an indication that the other answer with higher rep would help someone in the future.